# is there any variable which WordPress provides that can store data for the WP session?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I want to store the data of the logged-in user for the session of that user. For which I needed a Variable that can handle that data for the session of that user. After searching I have found the $wp_session variable which does but it returns Null for the admin_url hook. Please any insight on this appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it like this sentence

```
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
```

Make sure you add $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance(); before you try to echo the variable on page 2.

Comment: I have used this line on admin_url hook call and got error "Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Session' not found"